# How can I tell gulp to skip files it's already processed?

Tags: gulp

In the `gulpfile.js` below, I'd like for the `responsive` and `imageOptim.optimize` functions to not run if `originals/logos/a.jpg` already exists at `dist/logos/a.jpg`.

```
gulp.task('logos', function () {
  return gulp.src('originals/logos/*.{png,jpg}')
    .pipe(responsive({
      '*.*': sizes.map(function(size) {
        return {
          width: '' + (size * 100) + '%',
          rename: {
            suffix: size === 1 ? '' : ('@' + size + 'x')
          }
        }
      })
    }))
    .pipe(imageOptim.optimize())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/logos'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gulp 3

You can use `gulp-changed` for this. Any matched file that's in `'originals/logos/*.{png,jpg}'` and already in `'dist/logos'` will be filtered out before the `responsive` step:

```js
var changed = require('gulp-changed'); //         <----  add

gulp.task('logos', function () {
  return gulp.src('originals/logos/*.{png,jpg}')
    .pipe(changed('dist/logos')) //               <----  add
    .pipe(responsive({
      '*.*': sizes.map(function(size) {
        return {
          width: '' + (size * 100) + '%',
          rename: {
            suffix: size === 1 ? '' : ('@' + size + 'x')
          }
        }
      })
    }))
    .pipe(imageOptim.optimize())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/logos'));
});
```

### Update: Gulp 4

Use Gulp's [`lastRun()`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/lastrun) in combination with Gulp [`src`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src)'s option [`since()`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#options), no external dependencies needed.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');

function logos() { // <-- Gulp 4-ified this line
  return gulp.src(/* source glob here */, { since: gulp.lastRun(logos) }) // <-- added since:lastRun(name-of-this-function)
    /* -- your pipes here -- */
    .pipe(gulp.dest(/* destination path here */));
};
```

Or selectively import the Gulp pieces you need. In that example, only `src`, `dest`, and `lastRun` are used so

```js
const { src, dest, lastRun } = require('gulp');

function logos() {
  return src(/* source glob here */, { since: lastRun(logos) }) // <-- no `gulp.`s
    /* -- your pipes here -- */
    .pipe(dest(/* destination path here */)); // <-- no `gulp.`
};
```